# ios custom cell on table not showing image

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom cell loaded from my table, with an image and a label  the label shows ok but the image doesn't show

CustomCell.m

> ```
>    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:  (NSString*)reuseIdentifier
>   {
> self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];       
>                                        if (self) {
> // Initialization code
>     [self initLabels];
>     CGRect vintageScreenRect = CGRectMake(25, 0.0f, 100, 100);
>      self.iconImage = [[UIImage alloc]init];
>       UIImageView *vintageScreen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:vintageScreenRect];
>     //[vintageScreen setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vidButtonImg.png"]];
>     //    [vintageScreen setImage:self.iconImage];
>     [vintageScreen setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.tingo]];
>     vintageScreen.opaque = YES; // explicitly opaque for performance
>     [self.contentView addSubview:vintageScreen];
>     [vintageScreen release];
>      NSLog(@"tingo ::%@", self.tingo);
>     }
> return self;
>  }
> ```

UsingTable.m

> ```
>    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
>  {
> static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
>  CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
> if (cell == nil) {
>     cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
>        cell.tingo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"picsButtonImg.png"];
>      cell.iconName.text = @"d";
> } 
> return cell;
>    }
> ```

So the label shows ok , but the image doesn't show, I have tried with sending an uiImage and an NSString,

what is missing? thanks!

Comment: as artur pointed out in his answer, what does NSLog(@"tingo ::%@", self.tingo); gives you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.tingo` probably is nil in `initWithStyle` method. You are asigning `self.tingo` property after initWithStyle call.

That cause `[UIImage imageNamed:self.tingo]` is also nil, and the image simply doesn't exist.

You can fix it for example by custom setter of tingo property, or by making vintageScreen as property and set image "from outside".

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `tingo` is null when you first instantiate the cell. Doing `cell.tingo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"picsButtonImg.png"];` sets it to a value, but then your cell never knows to reset the image.

Move `vintageScreen` into a variable on your cell class, then override your `tingo` setter to reload the image if you want to keep the code you have in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

CustomCell.h

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {
    UIImageView *vintageImage;
    NSString *tingo;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *vintageImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *tingo;

@end
```

CustomCell.m

```
@implementation CustomCell
@synthesize vintageImage, tingo;

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString*)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];       
    if (self) {
        [self initLabels];
        [self addSubview:[self vintageScreen]];
    }
    return self;
}

-(UIImageView *)vintageScreen {
    if(vintageScreen == nil) {
       CGRect vintageScreenRect = CGRectMake(25, 0.0f, 100, 100);
       [self setVintageScreen:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:vintageScreenRect] autorelease]];
       [vintageScreen setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.tingo]];
       vintageScreen.opaque = YES;
    }

    return vintageScreen;
}

-(void)setTingo:(NSString *)newTingo {
    [tingo release];
    tingo = [newTingo retain];

    [[self vintageScreen] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:tingo]];
}
```

Comment: True, we did reach similar conclusions when answering.